# Selecting one column of a data frame returns a factor, instead of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I have the below code, if m ==2 then cd remains a dataframe and names(cd) are from the original dataframe d.
However if m == 3 only one column in the dataframe remains and cd turns into a factor and I lose the names...

```
samplesize <-100
g1 <- gl(2,samplesize/2,labels=c("V","M"))
g2 <- gl(3,samplesize/3,labels=c("V","M","U"))
m <- 2
d <- data.frame(g1,g2)
l <-  sapply(d,nlevels)
cd <- d[,l <= m]
names(cd)
```

I would like to keep the names of d even if the filter only leaves one column?

Comment: Try `cd <- d[,l <= m,drop=FALSE]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `drop=FALSE` to avoid coercing to the lowest dimension.

```
cd <- d[,l <= m, drop=FALSE]
names(cd)
[1] "g1"
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something like this... great! tx

Answer (score 1):

The classical problem of `[`, namely that it's default is `drop=TRUE`:

```
> args(`[.data.frame`)
function (x, i, j, drop = if (missing(i)) TRUE else length(cols) == 
    1) 
NULL
```

So (as said by P Lapointe), use `drop=FALSE`:

```
> cd <- d[,l <= m, drop = FALSE]
> names(cd)
[1] "g1"
```